# Can I still use Ubuntu 18.04 MATE on my Raspberry Pi?

Tags: 18.04, ubuntu-mate, ros

I am using [ROS Melodic](http://wiki.ros.org/melodic/Installation/Ubuntu), which supports up to Ubuntu 18.04. I know that [Ubuntu MATE 18.04 is no longer supported](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/ubuntu-mate-18-04-lts-reaches-end-of-life/23966), but can I still download it to my Raspberry Pi 3 and install packages onto it?

Comment: You can use `ubuntu-support-status` to see what packages still receive support; and what do not.  You'll get support for all packages from 'main', but not 'universe' etc., so you can assess yourself if you're happy with this environment.  If you're off-line there are no concerns, however I'm aware of Ubuntu-MATE team member(s) that still use 18.04, and myself I still have a Lubuntu 18.04 (i386) box I use on rare occasion

Answer (score 1):

If you have an ARMv8 version of Ubuntu 18.04, you can certainly install it, but there will be no guarantee that any of the repositories that offered software will still be operational. As it stands, [Ubuntu MATE only has images for 20.04.3 and 21.10 available](https://ubuntu-mate.org/download/arm64/) for the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: The 18.04 version can be found in the archive but my question is will it function well and if i install packages of ros will it work ?

Comment: You are in a much better position than me to answer both of these subjective questions. You have a Pi 3, and you have a source for an ARMv8-based Ubuntu MATE 18.04 installation. Give it a try. The worst that will happen is that you'll lose a few hours of time ....

Comment: What concerns me is eol term ( end of life) if the ubunto isnt supported does that mean than i cant install packages or use it for a project ?

Comment: EOL means there’s no support offered on this site or the Ubuntu MATE community site, and it means there is no guarantee that repositories will continue to exist. Of course, there will also be no security updates made available for the release going forward.